# contents of a file copied multiple times

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop, cp

copy contents of a file into all files of certain name.

using Linux command line.

```
cp myfile.txt old_file_a
cp myfile.txt old_file_b
cp myfile.txt old_file_c

for i in old_file* do; cp myfile.txt $i; done?
```

Comment: `for i in old_file_{a,b,c} do; cp myfile.txt "$i"; done`

Comment: `tee <myfile.txt old_file_{a,b,c} >/dev/null`.

Comment: @ooga your first semicolon is a little off

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in a b c; do cp myfile.txt old_file_$i; done
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain, someone flagged this.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Hope I don't get down rated for saying so.